# Limit LDAP users by OU

Tags: ldap, gitlab

To deny a LDAP user, we can use LDAP filter for Common Name i.e., CN as `'(!(cn=username))'`.

But how to deny by Organizational Unit i.e., OU? 
`'(!(ou=projectmail))'` not working.

I don't want to allow users with `ou` as `projectmail`

Comment: Please provide more information. Tree Structure? What you have tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My LDAP structure is `cn=user name,ou=group1,ou=company users,dc=company,dc=local` I dont want to allow users who have group name `ou=group1`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define a filter on the DN attributes, with the following filter:
`(ou:dn:=group1)`.

In your case, you may want to use `(!(ou:dn:group1))`

Comment: Only works on some LDAP Server implementations. (i.e. NOT Microsoft Active Directory)

Comment: Error:`Invalid credentials for username` for a valid user

Comment: Invalid credentials is the generic error that says that the user doesn't exist, the password is not matching or the server didn't even want to process the authentication for other security reasons.